# Dataframe output from sapply isn't a DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

The return value of my sapply function, *on one input item*, is a list rather than a data frame. I don't understand why. I know that sapply generally yields a list of all the return values; I'm confused why the return value of a single input is a list.

The example is a bit silly, but it makes the point.

```
> alphabet <- data.frame(letters = letters, numbers = 1:26)
> word <- c("w", "o", "r", "d")

> w <-sapply(word[1], function(x) {
    n <- alphabet[alphabet$letters == x,"numbers"]
    df <- data.frame(letter = x, number = n)
    return(df)
  }, USE.NAMES = F)

#        [,1]
# letter "w" 
# number 23
```

The output is a length-2 list, even though `df` should be a data frame.

I'd expect the output to be the same as calling `data.frame()` outside of the anonymous function:

```
> data.frame(letter = "w", number = 23) 
#   letter number
# 1      w     23
```

Why is my sapply output not in the same form as when I call `data.frame()` outside of `sapply()`?

Comment: `sapply` will never return a data.frame. The "s" is for simplify so it will either return a vector of an atomic type, or it will return a list. Note that a `data.frame` is really just a list with a special class. If you want to keep the class, use `lapply` which doesn't attempt to simplify the output.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the note. `lapply` returns the same, though?

Comment: You mean you ran `w <-lapply(word[1], function(x) {n <- alphabet[alphabet$letters == x,"numbers"];df <- data.frame(letter = x, number = n);return(df)})` and got the same thing? That doesn't seem right. You should get a list of length 1 with a data.frame inside. You'll always get a list out from `lapply` the same length as your input, but it wont' try to simplify the type.  If you don't want a list at all, it's unclear why you are using the `*apply` functions here.

Comment: @MrFlick Okay, nevermind, not sure what I did but `lapply` _does_ return a list with a dataframe inside. My end goal is to have a dataframe that combines all of data frames returned `lapply`'s list

Comment: Like @MrFlick said use `lapply` and after `do.call(rbind, w)`.

Comment: FYI, the tidyverse way to do it would be map_dfr(word, function(x) {... return(df)}).  map returns a list.  map_dfr specifically when the function returns a data frame, and you want to bind the rows all in one statement.

Comment: Thank you @Arthur, that was my next unasked question: how would you do this with tidy